# Sometimes Apps on SDcard Not Available As Clickable Icons

Tags: applications, home-screen, app-icons

I have an HTC Legend with Froyo 2.2. Occasionally it happens that after turning on the phone some icons on the home screen are not clickable, i.e. I only see the default icon as if I had uninstalled the app. This can happen to any app I have on my home screen, it's not related to just one. However, the Aldiko PDF reader seems to be affected more than others.

By now I know of two ways how to make the apps working again:

- the ol' "have you tried to turn it off and on again?"
- use a USB-cable and have my PC access it as a harddisk and then revoke that access and wait for the SDcard to initialise itself

In other words it seems to be a problem with the SDcard somehow.

Is there a shorter way to do this in case I have no USB-cable available, via the settings or something? Is there an app that can help me here? Can I code something?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's by definition – and the reason why you should never move apps to SD if they provide widgets you want to use.

SDCard gets mounted *after* the `boot_completed` broadcast has been sent. So apps installed on the SDCard are not able to receive this broadcast, and thus cannot provide their services "in advance". Depending on how fast your "homescreen" launches, it might already query the widgets before the mount was able to complete – and thus cannot find the apps installed there (which explains the "default icons").

Solution: Move those apps back from the SDCard if you need their widgets.

Comment: That makes sense. But where is the icon coming from? Isn't it stored in the phone memory? I mean the widget isn't doing anything, it's just there so I can click it.

Comment: Wait: Are we speaking about *widgets* (interactive icons displaying some information), *shortcuts* (to jump to a specific screen inside an app), or simple app-starter-icons here? You've used the term (and tag) "widget" here; but your comment rather seems to imply you didn't mean that.

Comment: Uhm, oops, I mean I drag an icon from the list of apps and drop it on the home-screen. So that's an app-starter-icon? Let me change the tags...

Comment: Yupp. And now my answer is no longer true, as it explicitly refers to *widgets*. I'll still let it stay, as it's at least related; but I've got no idea why simple app-icons should "blank out" in this context. Might be an issue with the launcher itself. Oh well, HTC and Android 2.2 – and you're using the HTC launcher coming with it? I remember Sense had a bunch of trouble of this kind...

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time there... As I didn't do anything with it, I assume it's the standard launcher.

Comment: Then it's most likely an issue with HTC Sense (I had that myself years ago, strange stuff with icons/widgets happening). You might try an alternative launcher then, but that won't support Sense specific stuff. At least using it for a while you could confirm whether HTC Sense is the culprit here.